# jQuery no longer works on AJAX return

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form that when submitted calls my AJAX and updates my database,

```
$(".bill-upd-submit").click(function() {
         var elem = $(this);
         $.post("update_bill.php", elem.parent(".bill-upd").serialize(), function(data) {
         // fade new data in
         elem.closest('li').html(data);
        });

    });
```

When the form is returned though, my jquery no longer works, Can anybody give me an idea of why?

Comment: Have you tried looking into browser console to check if there any javascript errors along with ajax form submission?

Comment: I've checked my console, no errors are logged.

Comment: is your `script` tag inside the `form` tag?

Comment: please add return false; at the end of your method.

Comment: No it isnt @MilkyWayJoe its at the end of my document before </body>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are replacing the element that has the event on it. Try using event delegation so that it stays bound.

```
$("body").on("click",".bill-upd-submit",function(){...});
```

Comment: @user766266 I suggest using a better context than "body" though.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
$(".bill-upd-submit").live("click",function(e)
```

instead of

```
$(".bill-upd-submit").click(function()
```

this may help you.